# Typeorm how to use relations in findOne()

Tags: typescript, postgresql, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I am using TypeORM for the first time and I got stuck trying to get an entry from another table using a FK. But I get this Error.

> Error: Relation "ingredientCategoryId" was not found; please check if
> it is correct and really exists in your entity.

**ingredient.entity**

```
@Entity('ingredient')
export class IngredientEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  ingredientCategoryId: number;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => IngredientsCategoryEntity,
    (ingredientsCategory) => ingredientsCategory.ingredient,
    { eager: true },
  )
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'ingredientCategoryId', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  ingredientsCategory: IngredientsCategoryEntity;
}
```

**ingredientsCategory.entity**

```
@Entity('ingredientsCategory')
export class IngredientsCategoryEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @OneToMany(
    () => IngredientEntity,
    (ingredient) => ingredient.ingredientsCategory,
  )
  ingredient: IngredientEntity[];
}
```

**ingredient.service**

```
  async getIngredientCategory(id: number): Promise<any> {
    const ingredient: IngredientEntity = await this.repo.findOne({
      where: { id: id },
      relations: ['ingredientCategoryId'],
    });
    return ingredient.ingredientsCategory;
  }
```

**ingredientsCategory.controller**

```
  @Get('/:id/ingredientsCategoryList')
  async getCategory(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number) {
    return this.ingredientService.getIngredientCategory(id);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
relations: ['ingredientsCategory'],
```

instead of:

```js
relations: ['ingredientCategoryId'],
```

Comment: same error  > Relation "ingredientCategory" was not found; please check if it is correct and really exists in your entity.

Comment: Hi. Did you use the singular (`ingredientCategory`) or the plural  (`ingredientsCategory`)?

Comment: I'm new to typeorm and sql, i have a basic understanding of it, what does relations actually mean ? ` const ePodCreationLink = await this.ePodCreationLinkRepository.findOne(ePodCreationLinkId, {
      relations: ['otps']
    });` trying to make sense out of this code

Comment: it means 'fetch those relations'